# SSRS Required parameter and optional parameter

Tags: reporting-services, parameters

I'm having a hard time figuring out how to make one parameter required and one optional.  This discussion seemed most like what I needed to do, but when I implement the solutions suggested I'm still having an issue. [SSRS Optional Parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18991847/ssrs-optional-parameters)

The situation: I have a batch that I need to run multiple receipts for but sometimes I'll need to run the receipt for just one member per batch.  So the batch number parameter is always required and the member parameter is optional (either all or one).

When I implement the solution suggested and I go to test with one member id I'm still getting receipts for all members.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending what your query looks like you can set your where clause to first filter out the batch then filter out the the member field if a value is passed.

```
WHERE Batch = @Batch_Param 
AND (@Member_Param is null OR Member = @Member_Param)
```

Make sure to Set your @Member_Param to allow NULL values.